# How can I show the print on the screen and not only on the console, after the action of clicking?

Tags: flutter

So basically I'm starting to work with flutter and I wanted to make some simple changes that I haven't been able to do alone in my test app,
they are:

- make gestureDetector onTap to detect the whole screen and not only the text
- show the prints on the screen as well and not only on the console, maintaining the action of only showing them after the click.

And that's all... very simple but it's been difficult for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp(
nome: 'John',
 ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
final String nome;
const MyApp({super.key, required this.nome});

@override
State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
 }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
int salary = 0;

void addSalary(int value) {
setState(() {
this.salary = this.salary + value;
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
print('User clicked');
addSalary(200);
print('salary changed to: $salary');
    },
child: Text('The salary of ${widget.nome} is $salary',
textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, the `GestureDetector` take the size of the child widget as default so you need to wrap it in the SizedBox having size of the full screen and add `translucent` in `behavior` parameter of `GestureDetector` to take tap in full screen.

And for the second question, in flutter you can't print the logs in the screen. just to see you can take some other widget for that and show it from there. like you need a one more `Text` widget to show the log.

You can refer to the below code for your solution.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String nome;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.nome});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int salary = 0;
  late String log;

  @override
  void initState() {
    log = '${widget.nome} is poor';
    super.initState();
  }

  void addSalary(int value) {
    setState(() {
      this.salary = this.salary + value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          print('User clicked');
          addSalary(200);
          print('salary changed to: $salary');
          log = 'salary changed to: $salary';
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('The salary of ${widget.nome} is $salary',
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            Text(log, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```